# remove extra letters and numbers from parenthesis in a string

Tags: java, string, character

I have a string like:

```
(aeiou 123) word one
```

How can I remove everything from the parenthesis so that only "word one" remains?

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: @Raj very little information provided, scope not defined

Comment: @Raj : Please provide the sample code you have attempted. This looks like a very easy problem however.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, e.g.:

```
String str = "(aeiou 123) word one";
str = str.replaceAll("\\([^\\)]*\\)", "").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ParanthesisRemoval {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String test="ab(xy)cd(zw)ef";

    boolean modified = true;
    while(modified)
    {
        modified = false;
        int indexOpenParanthesis = test.indexOf("(");
        int indexClosedParanthesis = test.indexOf(")");
        if(indexOpenParanthesis!=-1 && indexClosedParanthesis!=-1 && indexOpenParanthesis<indexClosedParanthesis)
        {
            int stringLength = test.length();
            test = test.substring(0, indexOpenParanthesis)+test.substring(indexClosedParanthesis+1, stringLength);
            modified=true;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(test);
}
```

}

note that this will not work for nested parantesis - (()), or paranthesis not properly  paired  (()